# Read data from previous step in JavaScript step in Pentaho

Tags: javascript, pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I have a column in csv file named `Account Rating` and I am using `Modified Java Script Value` step to create a new column using the rating column.
I want following new column:

```
Account Rating   New_Rating
---------------------------
Cold             ABC
Warm             DEF
Hot              XYZ
```

I tried following script in Java Script step:

```
var rating = getInputRowMeta().getString("Account Rating");
var new_rating = "Not assigned";

if (rating === 'Cold')
    new_rating = 'ABC';
else if (rating === 'Warm')
    new_rating = 'DEF';
else if (rating === 'Hot')
    new_rating = 'XYZ';
```

When I execute it, I am getting following error:

```
Can't find method org.pentaho.di.core.row.RowMeta.getString(string)
```

Can anyone help me with my script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep the **Field Name** which contains SPACE and can't be used as a JavaScript variable name, then you can modify your original code to first retrieve the index of the field from the RowMetaInterface object, and then get the corresponding value from that index:

```
var mapping = {
    'Cold' : 'ABC'
,   'Warm' : 'DEF'
,   'Hot' : 'XYZ' 
};

var idx = getInputRowMeta().indexOfValue("Accounting Rating");
var rating = row[idx];
var new_rating = mapping[rating] || 'Not assigned';
```

More info: https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/6.0/0R0/0V0/010/000/020/010

Answer (score 2):

You're overcomplicating the issue.

Before the answer, remember something, there are several steps, and combinations of steps, that achieve an incredible number of transformations to make usable patterns, **the last resort IS User defined Java Expression.**

Use the 'Value Mapper' step.

Here i used a Data Grid to generate your cold, warm hot data, and used the step for the mapping. If your use case is just for those 3 words, then this should fit, if you require something more robust you may need more steps, or perhaps even a script, but, remenber... Javscript is last resort.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, I am working on another complex transformation and this is just a sample transformation that I am trying. This will give me an understanding of how `Modified Java Script Value` step works. Transformations having integers or numbers are working as expected using JavaScript but not this one.

Comment: What is the whole thing ? Maybe i can help.